# How to get difference of changed input value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get difference between old value and the changed one?

```
$('input[name ="refresh"]').on("change paste keyup", function() {
   ???
});
```

So, this code (from another question) detects an input change, the input itself is number only, user set input's value from 10 to 25, how to get the difference between old and new values without pre-loading default values? By the way, default values bigger than 0.

Comment: "without pre-loading default values" unsure what that means

Comment: "pre-loading default values" means I manually set a variable with input's default value (like after page's been loaded)

Comment: So you are not setting the value on page load?? How are we supposed to know what the first value is?

Comment: This is what the question was, is it possible to get a previous value after change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the defaultValue of the element and it will have the initial value.

```js
$('input').on("input", function() {
   var defaultValue = +this.defaultValue;
   var currentValue = +this.value;
   console.log("defaultValue", currentValue, defaultValue, currentValue - defaultValue);
});

$('input').on("change", function() {
   var lastValue = this.dataset.last || this.defaultValue;
   var currentValue = +this.value;
   this.dataset.last = currentValue;
   console.log("last value", currentValue, lastValue, currentValue - lastValue);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" value="10" />
<input type="number" value="0" />
<input type="number" value="7" />
```

Or if you want to know what it was from the last time it was changed

```js
$('input').on("change", function() {
   var lastValue = this.dataset.last || this.defaultValue;
   var currentValue = +this.value;
   this.dataset.last = currentValue;
   console.log("last value", currentValue, lastValue, currentValue - lastValue);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" value="10" />
<input type="number" value="0" />
<input type="number" value="7" />
```

Comment: Doesn't the OP want the different between every input change, not just the initial? Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: Yep, that's what I've been trying to make. Thank you!

Comment: @evolutionxbox I answered it based on original wording which was default value.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the previous value with the `dataset` property of the element. Just wrap your listener to access and update the appropriate properties/attributes.

```js
const valueChangeWrapper = (e, func) => {
   const
    currVal = e.target.value,
    prevVal = e.target.dataset.previousValue;
  func(currVal, prevVal, e);
  e.target.dataset.previousValue = e.target.value;
}

const changeListener = (curr, prev, e) => {
  console.log(`Id: ${e.target.id}, Curr: ${curr}, Prev: ${prev}`);
};

const wrappedChangeListener = e => valueChangeWrapper(e, changeListener);

document.querySelectorAll('.listen').forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('change', wrappedChangeListener);
  el.addEventListener('paste', wrappedChangeListener);
  el.addEventListener('keyup', wrappedChangeListener);
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 4em !important; }

body {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-row-gap: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.25em;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="listen" id="input-1" />
<input type="text" class="listen" id="input-2" />
<input type="text" class="listen" id="input-3" />
<input type="text" class="listen" id="input-4" />
```